# How to start developing powerbi visuals in 2020

Tags: node.js, powershell, powerbi-custom-visuals

I've been struggling for the past hour to follow the installation tutorials for custom power bi visuals, but seem to be outdated --

[here](https://pastebin.com/pHJyfhfw) you can see the errors i amb getting

is there any time-proof tutorial to develop a sample visual from where I can start?

thank you

```
Windows PowerShell
```

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

Prueba la nueva tecnología PowerShell multiplataforma https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\berna> npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for powerbi-visuals-tools@3.1.9: wanted: {"node":"^10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.8.0","npm":"6.13.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: powerbi-visuals-tools@3.1.9

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-stack-parser
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'error-stack-parser@^2.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'friendly-errors-webpack-plugin'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-12T16_09_50_141Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\berna> npm i error-stack-parser
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-stack-parser
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'error-stack-parser@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-12T16_10_16_811Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\berna>

Answer (score 1):

aparently the powershell command is 
npm i -g powerbi-visuals-tools

this tutorial herer showed me the light 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSGimG8BRYg

regards to whoever is reading